# Need help in table creation for dropdown list

Tags: sql

I have table with name `Dates`. Fields are:

```
Date of Joining
Previous Date of Visit
Number of Visit
Reffered Department
```

For `Date of Joining` and `Previous Date of visit` fields, I'm entering the data from drop down list. Like: Select Day, Select Month, Select Year. Then how many fields should be created? How can I design the entire table? Please help.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135972/insert-data-in-multiple-table-with-single-button-click

Answer (score 0):

Design the table with DateTime values for those fields

DateOfJoining : datetime

PreviousDateOfVisit : datetime

Then its up to your UI to combine the selections of the split drop down fields back to one datetime parameter for inserting / updating, and vice versa for displaying.

This makes it far easier to query against these values.