# Insert data in multiple table with single button click

Tags: sql

I am developing project on hospital management. I am entering the data of Patien details. like

```
PatientsProfile:
Id,Name,Age, Address, ContactNo

PatientRelativeProfile:
Admittername,Age,Address,ContactNo, Relationship

Patients Defect Profile:
Injury_Accident, Murder_Attempt, Cancer, Other

Previous Treatment References:
Hospitalname, Doctorname, TestDone

Dates:
DateOfJoining, PreviousDateOfVisit, Numberofvisit, ReferredDepartment.
```

Note: For DateOfJoining and PreviousDateOfVisit values are taking from dropdownlist, for that in Dates table those type taken as DateTime.

All the above information are kept in one single page. I have only one submit button. After filling the page once I click on submit button all the data should be stored in corresponding tables.

Please somebody help me with query......

Comment: You have designed a data model, but you haven't considered the needed queries in the process?
Is this homework?

Answer (score -1):

sumit you should spend some time designing... things like what data needs to go into what table.. what should be the flow of your program. how individual queries would look like... its always a good idea to do some designing and then start coding

Comment: True. I find the data model rather naive (professionally speaking, no offense!)
Sumit, you'll want to create some ID's and look-up tables. For example, if you have a patient with a relative who is also a patient, you'll get some duplication. Make a PeopleProfile table, and let Patient and Relative be tables of roles that persons from the PeopleProfile table can have. And so on...